# How to get list of connected devices with Multipoint bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, headset

I am using multipoint bluetooth headset in my application and the headset is connected to more than one android devices.

I have created an application to list connected bluetooth devices and installed on one of the tablet. So in my application it shows that the tablet is connected with Bluetooth headset. But I also want the information that the with which other devices the bluetooth headset is connected? Can I get this information anyhow?

Does bluetoothheadset's getConnectedDevice() method extract the information from the bluetooth headset and tell me with which other devices Bluetooth headset is connected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you may have access to BT Headset code, you can implement an AT command to query the connected devices list from Bluetooth headset. I think none of the BT profiles provide this information.